# How to pass the dynamic path of a drawable to BitmapFactory.decoreResource()'s 2nd parameter

Tags: android, uri, bitmapfactory

I'm trying to implement `Bitmap memeCanvas = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), xxx).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);` to draw on the images that I upload from my phone to my `ImageView`.  Because I don't have a specific drawable path like `R.drawable.hypotheticalImage`, I don't know how to pass the same information for a drawable path that is dynamic as the 2nd parameter of `BitmapFactory.decodeResource()`.

I can supply code per request.

Comment: The `decodeResource()` method is only for drawable resources. Do you perhaps want the `decodeFile()` method instead?

Comment: @MikeM. So you mean like this `Bitmap memeCanvas = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageUri.getLastPathSegment()).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);` ?

Comment: Oh, no, not if you've got a `Uri`. Sorry, I thought you were referring to a file path. Assuming you got `imageUri` through the regular methods, you would do something like `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri))`.

Comment: @MikeM. No method for `getContentResolver()` in `decodeStream`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying. Assuming you're in a `Context` – e.g., an `Activity` – which seems likely, since you're calling `getResources()` in your `decodeResource()` example, the syntax I gave above is exactly correct.

Comment: @MikeM. I'm not sure.  When I put `decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri))`, getContentResolver was red.

Comment: What class are you in? That is, where exactly do you have that code?

Comment: @MikeM. In a fragment but I've already solved the problem.  Thank you very much for your help.  You can check my solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution.  I had to call `getContext()` to be able to access `getContentResolver()` and wrap the entire thing in a try-catch block.

```
Bitmap memeCanvas = null;
        try {
            memeCanvas = BitmapFactory
                    .decodeStream(getContext()
                            .getContentResolver()
                            .openInputStream(imageUri))
                    .copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```